# App Share extension network was lost

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, ios8-share-extension

I'm working on a share extension for one of my apps. I want to upload the selected file (any document) to a server, I have the endpoint, it's working with a current chrome app. When I start the dataTask, it returns in the

```
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: NSError?)
```

with the error `NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost."`

I have configured the `NSURLSession` like this:

```
let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier("group.myidentifier.background")
config.sharedContainerIdentifier = "group.myidentifier"

let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
let request = self.createRequest(id: randomID, name: fileName, type: mime!, file: NSData(contentsOfURL: fileURL)!, filename: fileName, mimetype: mime!)

let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request)
task.resume()
```

The `createRequest` method creates a form to post.

I don't close the extension when the upload starts, tried with Alamofire too, but that's not working neither.

Any advice is welcome, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you can check these tutorials.

https://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/ios8-day-by-day-day-2-sharing-extension
http://www.appcoda.com/ios8-share-extension-swift/

and I think your delegateQueue should be nil.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but these tutorials almost does the same thing as me, except that the appcoda uses imgur's upload class, and the other uses json based image upload. But the session configuration part is identical to my config.